# Modal JDialog disappearing behind parent on solaris CDE

Tags: java, swing, solaris

My code contains a JFrame which after a certain action, shows a non-modal JDialog. The user is expected to drag an object from the JFrame into the JDialog. The issue I'm having is only showing up on Solaris CDE (Common Desktop Environment): opening JDialog correctly positions the window on top of the frame. After the user clicks on the frame, dialog disappears behind it forcing the user to re-position the frame to put it besides JDialog. The expected behavior is for the JDialog to remain on top of the parent frame.

The following code demonstrates the situation:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{

    public MyFrame()
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Push me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(MyFrame.this);
                dialog.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("I'm a dialog!!!"));
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }

        });

        getContentPane().add(btn);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

This problem is not when running any other window manager on solaris as well as windows and linux (GNOME). A similar question has been asked some time ago ([How to make modeless dialog stay on top of its parent in Solaris CDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754866/how-to-make-modeless-dialog-stay-on-top-of-its-parent-in-solaris-cde)), but it remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Both `JFrame` and `JDialog` inherit the following `Window` convenience methods: [toFront()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29) and [toBack()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toBack%28%29), although `JDialog` inherits the latter from `Dialog`. Anyway, try using either of those in combination with a [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) by listening for the following events: [windowActivated(WindowEvent e)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowActivated%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) and [windowDeactivited(WindowEvent e)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowDeactivated%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29).

**Edit:**

This what someone else [suggested](http://www.coderanch.com/t/336570/GUI/java/JDialog-non-modal-always-top),

> attach a focus listener on the JDialog
>   and when it loses focus, move it to
>   the front of all the other windows.
>   This will cause flickering and works
>   pretty horribly.

Comment: toFront() activates the current window (in this case the JDialog). This prevents the user from being able to interact with the parent frame.

Comment: @Greg: the idea was to catch the `windowActivated` event on the `JFrame` and call `dialog.toFront()`, or `frame.toBack()`. Once again, there is no guarantee that this will work, but I thought it may be worth a try.

Comment: That's what I did. This causes the following behavior: when the user attempts to click on the frame, the listener kicks in and activates the dialog (or deactivates the frame). This makes the app behave erratically.

Comment: @Greg: See my edit ... looks like there's no easy workaround. :(